# Adding color to header as it scrolls down page on Wordpress Genesis Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i need some help for this.

The header of http://veritaswaste.com/waste/ needs to go from empty / clear to a light blue color (#C5D0DE) as the user scrolls down the page.

I'm not sure if this is best done with Javascript or with CSS.

Somebody help me please.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

in you javascript:

```
var _window = $(window),
header = $('.header'),
max = 1,
opacity = parseFloat(header.css('opacity')),
currentOpacity = opacity,
scrollPos = _window.scrollTop();

_window.scroll(function() {  
if (scrollPos < _window.scrollTop() ) {
    header.css('opacity', currentOpacity=currentOpacity+0.1);
} else if (scrollPos > _window.scrollTop() && currentOpacity > opacity) {
    header.css('opacity', currentOpacity=currentOpacity-0.1);
}

if (_window.scrollTop() == 0)
    header.css('opacity', opacity);

scrollPos = _window.scrollTop();
});
```

and in your header:

```
.header{
display:block;   
width:100%;
padding:10px 0;
background:red;
opacity:0;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a JavaScript job. Assuming you can use jQuery, here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gy2wW/

Basically, there are 3 steps. First hook into `$(window).scroll`. Then get the current scroll position relative to the window and divide (that's the `$(document).scrollTop() / $(document).height();` bit). Then apply to the header using `$("#header").css('opacity',newOpacityValue);`

Comment: Ok, so where should i put this codes

$(window).scroll(function(){
            var newOpacityValue = $(document).scrollTop() / $(document).height();
            $("#header").css('opacity',newOpacityValue);
        })

I'm new to this. please help. I am working this in Genesis framework

thanks a lot for your patience and support.

regards,
rod

Comment: Hi Rodney. With reference to the URL you supplied, I'm assuming that you just want the header background to change colour and for the text to stay the same. For this you'll need to add a little extra html to the inside of your <header> tag. Immediately inside your header, add the following: '<div id="headerBackground"></div>' Then add a new script tag to the bottom of your <head> element and put the javascript I used in the jsFiddle inside it. You'll need to change '$("#header").css('opacity',newOpacityValue);' to '$("#headerBackground").css('opacity',newOpacityValue);'

Comment: Then add this css to your stylesheet: 'width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid red;
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
z-index: -500;'

Comment: Sorry, I mean, add this css to your stylesheet: #headerBackground {width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; z-index: -500;}